# On solving $x^\frac{3}{2}=a$ and MaxExtraConditions

Tags: equation-solving

In V 14

```
ClearAll[x, a]
Solve[x^(3/2) == a, x]
```

Gives

[image]

Maple 2024 gives what I think is the right solutions

```
restart;
solve(x^(3/2)=a,x)
```

[image]

It is easy to see that the above should be the solution. Let us write  $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ as ${(x^{\frac{1}{2}})}^3$ then let $y = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ then the equation becomes  $y^{3}=a$ and now Mathematica gives

```
Solve[y^3==a,y]
```

[image]

Replacing $y$ in the above back with $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and now solving for $x$ gives the solution the same as Maple (i.e. 3 roots)

```
% /. Rule[y, any_] :> x^(1/2) == any
```

[image]

```
 Map[Solve[#, x] &, %]
```

[image]

The above is what I have expected to be generated automatically.

ps. After writing all the above, I found that

```
ClearAll[x, a]
Solve[x^(3/2) == a && a != 0, x, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

Gives

[image]

help says `MaxExtraConditions -> All` gives  non-generic solutions. Not sure what this means now.

So my question is: why is `MaxExtraConditions -> All` needed to obtain all solutions? Should solve have given all these solutions automatically without the need for an option?

Since solve works in complex domain automatically?   Note that `x^(3/2)` can always be written as `(x^(1/2))^3`  Which is the same as `y^3` where `y` is new name for `x^(1/2)`. This is true for any `x`.

So why is `MaxExtraConditions -> All` needed here?

Comment: How about the result of `Solve[x^(3/2) == a, x, Method -> Reduce]` which is `{{x -> a^(2/3)}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-(-1)^(1/3) a^(
     2/3), -(-(-1)^Rational[1, 3] a^Rational[2, 3])^Rational[
        1, 2] + (-1)^Rational[2, 3] a^Rational[1, 3] == 0]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(-1)^(2/3) a^(
     2/3), -((-1)^Rational[2, 3] a^Rational[2, 3])^Rational[
        1, 2] - (-1)^Rational[1, 3] a^Rational[1, 3] == 0]}}`?